# Direct Image and the induced representation.

Tags: representation-theory, sheaf-theory, principal-bundles, etale-cohomology, galois-representations

Suppose $f \colon \mathrm{Spec}\, L \to \mathrm{Spec}\, K$ be a finite covering. Given a smooth sheaf ${\cal F}_{\rho}$ on $\mathrm{Spec}\,L$ corresponding to the representation $\rho \colon {\pi}_1(\mathrm{Spec}\,L) \to \mathrm{GL}_n(\Bbb{Z}_l)$, we will consider the direct image $f_* {\cal F}_{\rho}$ on $\mathrm{Spec}\,K$.

Q. Why does $f_* {\cal F}_{\rho}$ coincide with the one induced by the induced representation of $\pi_1(\mathrm{Spec}\,K)$ by way of $\pi_1(\mathrm{Spec}\,L) \to \pi_1(\mathrm{Spec}\,K)$?

Comment: If you know that $f^*$ correspond to restriction of the representation via $\pi_1(\operatorname{Spec} L)\to \pi_1(\operatorname{Spec} K)$, this follows by uniqueness of adjoint.